# Tooltip not showing only on hover

Tags: html, css, tooltip

This is my code,I want to display the tooltip, only when i hover over the anchor tags, Initally I have hidden the visibilty and only want to show on hover. But The tooltip is not getting shown when I am hovering over it and I am not getting any error on console aswell. what I am doing wrong here? Can anyone please help

```css
body {
  font-family: Bogle, Bogle, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
}

.spanhead1 {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 69px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.spanhead2 {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 48px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.spanhead1 .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #e1edf9;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.spanhead1 .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e1edf9 transparent;
}

.spanhead1:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.spanhead2 .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #e1edf9;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.spanhead2 .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e1edf9 transparent;
}

.spanhead2:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>xcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  <div class="links">
    <span class="spanhead1">
      <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="winperson_folowup()" style="color: rgb(0,113,206);">Open Door (ODP-)</a>
      <span class="tooltiptext">For opendoor</span>
    </span>
    <span class="spanhead2">
      <a href="https://xyz" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0,113,206);">Ethics (IIMT-)</a>
      <span class="tooltiptext">For Inperson</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now you changed the code of your question so that it doesn't show the issue anymore. For everyone who stumbles over that: the tooltips were visible all the time, not only on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tooltips are showing up just at the bottom of the page below i better positioned the tooltip on the left.

```css
body {
  font-family: Bogle, Bogle, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
}

.spanhead1 {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 69px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.spanhead2 {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 48px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.spanhead1 .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #e1edf9;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 120%;
  left: 45%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.spanhead1 .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e1edf9 transparent;
}

.spanhead1:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.spanhead2 .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #e1edf9;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.spanhead2 .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e1edf9 transparent;
}

.spanhead2:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>xcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  <div class="links"><span class="spanhead1"><a href="javascript:void()" onclick="winperson_folowup()" style="color: rgb(0,113,206);">Open Door (ODP-)</a>
    <span class="tooltiptext">For opendoor</span>
    </span>
    <span class="spanhead2">
    <a href="https://xyz" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0,113,206);">Ethics (IIMT-)</a>
    <span class="tooltiptext">For Inperson</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is related to the original question**

---

**First:** I found some issues:

- The two span texts are swaped.
- There is no `position` property defined for any parent of the tooltip. Therefor `bottom` refers to the `body`. You could solve this by setting the container `div.links` to `position: relative`.
- You are using the wrong selectors for the tooltips, for example `.spanhead1 .tooltiptext`. Since they are no children of `a.spanhead...` it should be only `.tooltiptext`.

---

You could use the adjacent sibling selector `+` for selecting the next sibling of the hovered element, for example:

```css
.spanhead1:hover + .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

**Working example:**

I compressed the CSS a bit:

- I removed the double tooltip definition,
- merged the single values for `margin-top`, `-left` etc. into one shorthand `margin` and
- removed the definition for `.header` because there is none in the example HTML.

Furthermore i used an attribute selector `a[class^="spanhead"]`, which means select every anchor with a class that begins with `spanhead`. Alternatively you could add an extra class that is only `spanhead`.

```css
body {
  font-family: Bogle, Bogle, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

.links {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a[class^="spanhead"] {
  width: 69px;
  margin: 20px 15px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.spanhead2 {
  width: 48px;
}

.tooltiptext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #e1edf9;
  color: #000;
}

.tooltiptext::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e1edf9 transparent;
  content: "";
}

a[class^="spanhead"]:hover + .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>xcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  <div class="links">
    <a class="spanhead1" href="javascript:void()" onclick=" person_folowup()">Open Door (ODP-)</a>
    <span class="tooltiptext">For opendoor</span>
    <a class="spanhead2" href="xyz.com">Ethics (IMT-)</a>
    <span class="tooltiptext">For ethics</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Alternativly you could omit `+` if you would nest the tooltips inside the anchors. The advantage is that you can set the spanheads itself to `position: relative` (instead of `div.links`) so that the tooltips are under its spanhead instead of both at the same position horizontally centered.

**Working example:**

I added an extra class `.spanhead` to omit the attribute selector.

```css
body {
  font-family: Bogle, Bogle, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.spanhead {
  position: relative;
  width: 69px;
  margin: 20px 15px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.spanhead2 {
  width: 48px;
}

.tooltiptext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #e1edf9;
  color: #000;
}

.tooltiptext::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e1edf9 transparent;
  content: "";
}

.spanhead:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>xcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  <div class="links">
    <a class="spanhead spanhead1" href="javascript:void()" onclick=" person_folowup()">Open Door (ODP-)
      <span class="tooltiptext">For opendoor</span>
    </a>
    <a class="spanhead spanhead2" href="xyz.com">Ethics (IMT-)
      <span class="tooltiptext">For ethics</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is Bootstrap 5 doc. I hope you can get help from this.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/

Comment: HI Fida, welcome to the community. Thanks for your answer, sadly it is not helpful. That's why you have gotten the downvote. You assume that this is a bootstrap issue when nothing indicates that it has anything to do with bootstrap.